# What is the Dragonfire scorestreak and how do I use it?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I haven't had the game long and have only been playing online multiplayer so far. I just earned the Dragonfire scorestreak but I dont know how to use it. Everytime I tried with the conventional method of pressing right on the d-pad, it just kept saying that I couldn't use that here. I tried it inside, outside, against the floor, against a wall, against a vehicle... nothing!

Anybody know how I am supposed to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is glitchy.

http://forums.activision.com/thread/200530181

http://community.callofduty.com/message/413520564

Comment: it has been fixed with the last patch :)

Answer (score 0):

You need space on the ground in front of you to launch Dragonfire.

Comment: how much space?? I tried it on an open road with plenty of space in front. Do you need to look up? straight ahead? down?